# Manipulate list in function

Tags: list-manipulation

I have some problems with lists and functions.
Basically I just want to cut all entries from the right side, which contain 2.
({2,1,2} should become {2,1})

```
Mask[i_] := IntegerDigits[i, 3]
CutRight[l_] := Module[{m},
    m = l;
    For[i = Lenght[l], i > 0,i--,
        If[m[[i]] == 2, Drop[m, i],i=0];
        ]
    m]
Mask[89]
CutLeft[%]
```

Output:

> ```
> {1, 0, 0, 2, 2}
>
> {Null, 0, 0, 2 Null, 2 Null}
> ```

But I was hoping for `{1, 0, 0}`

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood it correctly:

```
{1, 0, 0, 2, 2} //. {l__, 2} -> {l}
(*{1, 0, 0}*)
```

If you want it as a function, just wrap it as in

```
CutRight[l_] := l //. {a__, 2} -> {a}
```

#### Silly benchmark following Michael's comment:

```
timing = Table[
   list = ConstantArray[1, pre]~Join~ConstantArray[2, pos];
   {pos,
     {Do[list /. {x___, 2 ..} :> {x}, {30000}] // Timing // First,
      Do[list //. {x___, 2} -> {x}, {30000}] // Timing // First}} // Thread
   , {pre, 0, 9, 3}, {pos, 0, 10}];

ListLinePlot[#, PlotLegends -> {"Replace", "ReplaceRepeated"}] &@* Transpose /@ timing;
Show[%, PlotRange -> All] //. Legended[Legended[a___], ___] :> Legended[a]
```

[image: Plot results]

(Vertical) Time x Number of trailing 2's (Horizontal). 
The stacked lines are, from bottom to top, 0, 3, 6 and 9 elements before the 2's

It's nice to see recursion gradually taking it's toll!

Comment: This is very nice and compact.  I didn't know about  `//.`

Comment: `ReplaceRepeated`! It can bite sometimes, though... "You should be very careful", the documentation says!

Comment: There's this, too: `{1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2} /. {x___, 2 ..} :> {x}`

Comment: Oh, nicer and safer! Why is RuleDelayed necessary there?

Answer (score 1):

Try `Position` with `Delete` or just use `DeleteCases`.

```
list = IntegerDigits[89, 3]
(* {1, 0, 0, 2, 2}  *)

Delete[list, Position[list, 2]]
(* {1, 0, 0} *)

DeleteCases[list, 2]
(* {1, 0, 0} *)
```

## **Update for "right side"**

```
midpoint = Floor[Length[list]/2]
list[[1 ;; midpoint]]~Join~DeleteCases[list[[midpoint + 1 ;;]], 2]
(* {1, 0, 0} *)
```

## **Update for "right side until not 2"**

```
list[[1 ;; Length@list - Length@TakeWhile[Reverse@list, # == 2 &]]]
```

also

```
list[[1 ;; Length@list - LengthWhile[Reverse@list, # == 2 &]]]
```

Comment: I can't access Mathematica at the moment, but wouldn't this delet all 2's? I just want the ones on the right side to be gone.

Comment: Define "right side".  Second half of the list?

Comment: Sorry if this was unclear: {2,2,2,2,1,2}->{2,2,2,2,1}
every 2 until the first different number (from right side).

Comment: Dude, I'm going to have to start charging you. LOL!

Answer (score 1):

```
A = {5,4,7,5,9,2,2,6,2,2};
Take[A, Length[A] - Length@TakeWhile[Reverse[A], # == 2 &]]
```

Comment: You can use `LengthWhile` instead of `Length@TakeWhile`, too